# Change iframe src through js

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

So coming straight to the problem, i am writing a js which should change the **src** of **iframe** if screen resolution changes

```
<script language="javascript">
function newframe()
{
    var w = screen.width;
    var srchframe = document.getElementById("proj");
    var targetURL1 = "http://wms.indianpropertynetwork.com/exchange/frames/clients.featured_projects.asp?cnt=5&wd=880&prj=1";   
    var targetURL2 = "http://lpm.indianpropertynetwork.com/exchange/frames/clients.featured_projects.asp?cnt=4&wd=668&prj=1";   

    if (srchframe.src != targetURL1 && w > 1300  )
    {srchframe.src = targetURL1 }

    else 
    { srchframe.src = targetURL2 }  
}   
</script>
```

and calling this function in the following iframe

```
<iframe id="proj" onload="newframe();" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" width="100%" height="200px" frameborder="0" scrolling="No" ></iframe>
```

The problem with script is it keeps on loading both the url in alternate order and won't stop loading.

Answer (score 0):

You are using onload handler to start another load cycle, so continuously reloading is what your code seems to be intended to do.

Your code:

1. What to do on page load in iframe? Call newFrame().
   This is in your code reading `onload="newframe();"`
2. newFrame() is setting frames src causing it to load another page.
   Your `if` is assigning new URL to `src` of `srchframe` on any invocation of `newframe()`. And for it's loading URL 1 if current isn't URL 1 and URL 2 otherwise it is actually resulting in swapping both URLs.
3. Due to having switched pages in 2. another onload event will be triggered.

The essential problem is: by assigning URL to `srchframe.src` that frame's page gets replaced to load another one. So don't adjust the src property of iframe unless it is actually intended to load another page this way.

Basically you should try different approach. Take it as described initially:

> should change the **src** of **iframe** *if screen resolution changes*

So you shouldn't bind to onload event of iframe, but to onresize event of outer window. Even though this isn't acting on changing screen resolution it is all better than your approach. Eventually try media queries as proposed in my answer to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23198520/website-adapting-to-different-monitor-sizes/23198630#23198630

Answer (score 0):

Execute your function only once as onLoad is called on every change of src , for this purpose you can do with the help of a bool, below is the code you can use:

**HTML:**

```
<script language="javascript">
var newFrameCalled = false;
function newframe()
{
    if(newFrameCalled)
        return;
    var w = screen.width;
    var srchframe = document.getElementById("proj");
    var targetURL1 = "http://wms.indianpropertynetwork.com/exchange/frames/clients.featured_projects.asp?cnt=5&wd=880&prj=1";   
    var targetURL2 = "http://lpm.indianpropertynetwork.com/exchange/frames/clients.featured_projects.asp?cnt=4&wd=668&prj=1";   

    if (srchframe.src != targetURL1 && w > 1300  )
    {srchframe.src = targetURL1 }

    else 
    { srchframe.src = targetURL2 }
    newFrameCalled = true;  
}   
</script>
```

Hope this helps.